# How to use jQuery in Firefox plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, plugins

I'm trying to create a Firefox plugin and I would like to use some jQuery functions. How to include needed jQuery libraries? Some way to include the libraries to the plugin itself?

I need to show a jQuery Dialog type window on various web sites when user clicks a link injected to the page.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If the OP really means extension, not plugin, then this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension

Comment: remember -- extension = greasemonkey, firebug, colorfultabs, etc. Plugin = flash, quicktime, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `overlay.xul` file, just include it as if you were including any other Javascript file:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://my-firefox-extension/content/path/to/jquery.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using chrome dialogs instead of jQuery. I've written a similar extension, though I didn't use a jQuery, but dialog code written by myself. The problem is that when you inject your html dialog inside some random page, in many cases it will come distorted because of unpredictable clashes with the loaded site CSS. Even when using inline styles and all other tricks.

In the end, I've looked how Google notebook extension is implemented and used the same idea. It worked great.

Comment: do you know whether there is any ff extensions which use jquery?