# Is there a dojo or a Jquery just for Firefox add on development?

Tags: firefox-addon, javascript

Started working on Firefox add ons, which is done with JavaScript and XUL, and I find myself sorely wanting to use Dojo or someother kind of JavaScript like library, but I can't find one that exists. So I was thinking of starting a library by porting Dojo over to a Firefox add on specific fork. Get rid off the cross browser stuff, use array comprehension and other nice stuff available in Firefox's JavaScript engine. I worry about whether or not there's enough of a userbase who'd take advantage of this, but more than that I guess I'm wondering if there's already something like this? Google finds nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozilla Corp developed a JavaScript library for this purpose: [FUEL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/FUEL).

it is developed by John Resig the creator of jQuery.

To know how to use jQuery inside FF extension look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery, at least, functions perfectly well when embedded in a Firefox addon.  I can't quote you names, but I've heard that several popular addons are already using jQuery.

Here's [an article](http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/jquery-and-dynamic-html-in-xul.html) discussing using jQuery within XUL and some of the hoops you may need to jump through.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly common to embed jQuery in firefox extensions.