# Can I use a Javascript framework within my Firefox Addons?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, javascript-framework

I'm writing a Firefox Addon and I was wondering if I could take advantage of frameworks such as jQuery within my Firefox addon source code? Would it be as simple as including the jquery JS file within my addon's package folder and linking to it in my XUL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hit on Google for 'firefox addon using jQuery' points to:

http://gluei.com/blog/view/using-jquery-inside-your-firefox-extension

[How to use jQuery in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension)