# Is there a way to disable all other Java Scripts other than my own with Grease Monkey

Tags: jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I need help getting a Grease Monkey with JQuery Script to run on a broken site.

I'm trying to get the following GM script to run, but the page I want it to work on has a JS error and my JS does not get executed.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          BILL INFO PAGE ALTER
// @namespace     http://jenkinslaw.org
// @description   Alter the web page in order to pretty print
// @include       http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/billinfo/bill_history.cfm?*
// @require       http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

// ==/UserScript==
*/
(function() {

  //Make a copy of the bill table
  var bill_table = $('.main_table').clone();

  //empty the whole lot
  $(body).empty();

  //append the bill back to the dom.
  $(body).append(bill_table);

}());
```

Thanks!

D

### Progress:

I agree with @mkoryak this is an impossible problem to solve with GM.  So I'm dropping it and using a Firefox extension instead (hopefully it wont run into the same issue).

I'll be following the example I saw on another post here on OS:
[How to use jQuery in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension)

**I was able to get it working but with a slight modification from the example shown:**

*(As an aside, I used the [Firefox Extension Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) to get a basic framework of the extension set-up easily and quickly).*

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){

billinfo = new function(){};
billinfo.log = function(){ Firebug.Console.logFormatted(arguments,null,"log"); };
billinfo.run = function(doc,aEvent) {

  // Check for website
  if(!doc.location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(.*\.)?legis\.state\.pa\.us\/cfdocs\/billinfo\/bill_history\.cfm\?(.*)?$/i)) return; 

  // Check if already loaded
  if(doc.getElementById("plugin-billinfo")) return;

  // Setup
  this.win = aEvent.target.defaultView.wrappedJSObject;
  this.doc = doc;

  //Make a copy of the bill table
  bill_table = $('.main_table', doc).clone();

  //empty the whole lot
  $('body', doc).empty();

  //append the bill back to the dom.
  $('body', doc).append(bill_table);      
}; 

// Bind Plugin
var delay = function(aEvent){ var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; setTimeout(function(){ billinfo.run(doc,aEvent); },1); };
var load = function(){ gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", delay, true); };
window.addEventListener("pageshow", load, false) 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do that with GM.  I don't have direct access to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it.

If there is a javascript error, your code (which executes last) will never execute.

I have looked **far and wide** for a solution for this, but was never able to find it.

Comment: Do you know if a firefox extension would run into the same problem?

Comment: i dont know, but my guess would be that it would.

Comment: @DKinzer: if you are going to try the extension route, you should look into compiling a GM plugin into an extension. i think this is possible, it might save you a step or 2

Answer (score 1):

GM and jQuery 1.4.* currently fail to co-exist due to an error in the `eventSupported` function.
Therefore, you can use the 1.3.* jQuery or include a modified 1.4.2 version directly in your script, such as the one suggested [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error).
Since you have chosen to take the extension path, this is irrelevant to you, but I still post this for others with similar issues who might stumble upon this in the future.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually still useful to know.  Though I did solve my problem via the extension route already.