# How to create an object from the location/URL value in JavasScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I need a way to create an `object` from a location value.  For example if I have the value:

'http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/billinfo/bill_history.cfm?**syear**=*2007*&**sind**=*0*&**body**=**S**&**type**=*B*&**bn**=*1*'

which I get from `doc.location.href();`

I would like to make the following object:

```
myObject = {

  syear : '2007',
  snid  : '0',
  body  : 's',
  type  : 'B',
  bn    : '1',

};
```

Thanks!

D

---

#### Progress

For some reason I couldn't get the [extended function/object](http://www.mathias-bank.de/jQuery/jquery.getUrlParam.js) to work in [my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685581/is-there-a-way-to-disable-all-other-java-scripts-other-than-my-own-with-grease-mo).  I think because my code is running inside a firefox extension and outside of the document context.  Or maybe it had something to do with the `jQuery.noConflict();` (I don't know).

But, I ended up needing to take out the function from the [object](http://www.mathias-bank.de/jQuery/jquery.getUrlParam.js) and editing it a little in order to get it to work for me:

```
function getURLParam(URL, strParamName){

  var qString;
  var returnVal = new Array();

  if (URL==null) return null;

  if ( URL.indexOf("?") > -1 ){
    var strQueryString = URL.substr(URL.indexOf("?")+1);
    qString = strQueryString.split("&");
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }

  for (var i=0;i<qString.length; i++){
    if (escape(unescape(qString[i].split("=")[0])) == strParamName){
      returnVal.push(qString[i].split("=")[1]);
    }

  }  

  if (returnVal.length==0) return null;
  else if (returnVal.length==1) return returnVal[0];
  else return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be useful:

http://www.mathias-bank.de/2006/10/28/jquery-plugin-geturlparam/

using the above you can easily construct the hash

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  And the source code is very small.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Url Parser](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/#footer) should do exactly what you want.

```
jQuery.url.setUrl('http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/billinfo/bill_history.cfm?syear=2007&sind=0&body=S&type=B&bn=1').param('syear');
```

returns `2007`