# How to change jQuery default context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I loaded jQuery on a Firefox addon, which causes it to load using XUL's `window`.

I want to change the default context so it will use the correct `window` object.

The classic example I always see is:

```
var $ = function(selector,context){
   return new  jQuery.fn.init(selector,context|| correctWindow );
};
$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

But doing it I kill a lot of functions, like `.ajax`, `.browser`, ... I need these methods.

[AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) won't let me create an wrapper to `jQuery` to send the correct `window` object.

So my only option is to somehow change jQuery's default context without changing its source code.

What options do I have?

Comment: Previous answer that should help:<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690529/437226

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override default jQuery selector context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690447/override-default-jquery-selector-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first content script I added

```
var loader = Components
    .classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);

loader.loadSubScript("chrome://extensions/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js");

var initjQuery = jQuery.fn.init;
$.fn.init = function(s,c,r) {
    c = c || window.document;
    return new initjQuery(s,c,r);
};
```

This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You change the default context with this wrapper:

```
jQuery.fn.init2 = jQuery.fn.init;

jQuery.prototype.init = function (selection, context, root) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init2(selection, context, jQuery.context || root);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.context = $(newContextSelector);
    $("*").css("color", "red");
});
```

Look at context that is a jquery object.