# Set jQuery selector context for whole block of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

The second parameter of jQuery allows you to specify the context in which to search for the selector. For example:

```
$('.some-selector', '#some-context')
```

Searches for `$('.some-selector')` within `$('#some-context')` - essentially equivalent to `$('#some-context').find('.some-selector')`.

Is there some way to search within a context for a whole block of code containing jQuery selectors, without explicitly setting the context parameter for each one? Some sort of `with` type of thing?

My scenario is that I have a page with 4 iframes, and I have a bunch of code that contains jQuery selectors, but I want all those selectors to search not only within the main document (default behavior), but also within each of the documents of the 4 iframes. Right now I have a variable $domContext that contains the main document as well as the documents of the 4 iframes, so I can search all 5 documents like this:

```
$('.some-selector', $domContext)
```

Which is fine for one line, but I have a bunch of code that this needs to be done for (in fact scattered throughout a ~500 line file). Any better way, or is there no way around it?

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690447/override-default-jquery-selector-context.

Comment: Just the kind of thing I was looking for - thanks!