# jQuery in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I would like to include jQuery in a Firefox extension.

I add the following line of code to import the jQuery file:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://js/jquery.js", window.content.document);
```

Firefox runs the file immediately after importing.  The jQuery file looks like this with an anonymous closures:

```
 (function( window, undefined ) {
        ...bunch of code....
       _jQuery = window.jQuery,
 })(window);
```

When the extension runs there is an error "window is not defined".  What is a way to give jQuery access to the window?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension ?

Comment: There they use the <script> tag to import into the global namespace. "Components.utils.import" allows for a second parameter to specify the scope where you want to import to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this to your *.xul file to include jQuery.

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="toolbar.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but on normal websites, jQuery is loaded into the context of `window`. Therefore, you have to use [`window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content) as scope:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://js/jquery.js", window.content);
```

`window.content.document` does not contain a property `window`.

Comment: This did not work for me. I even tried this: `var scope = { window: contentWindow };` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it's same as for greasemonkey userjs, try using an `unsafeWindow`, not the `window`.