# Using jQuery extension in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension that uses coda-slider to move between photos.  Coda-slider requires that jQuery be available.  Is there a way to include jQuery, after the page has loaded, in the DOM of the page so that after it is inserted it is loaded?

Comment: You have asked [the same question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137353/jquery-in-firefox-extension). You got two answers for that. Did they not work? If not, why not? Please don't ask questions twice but comment on the answer given to it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your extension can use JavaScript:

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
// or whatever other url you want to get jQuery from.
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Source for this snippet: [Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet).

Answer (score 2):

Using the subscript loader component works great. The only disadvantage is that you have to include jQuery as a local resource (either in chrome or as a module). For example:

```
var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
             .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/jquery-1.5.2.min.js");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIJSSubScriptLoader

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuerify`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12632/versions/) plugin for firefox. It is also available for chrome also but not sure

Comment: The way I read the question suggests the OP wants to include jQuery from within the extension he's writing; can jQuerify be called programatically?