# FireFox addon making toolbar icons disappear

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, manifest, toolbar

I just completed mine first FF add-on .
But after install it making the existing toolbar icons to disappear.

This is how mine chrome.manifest file looks like.

```
content myext content/ 
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul    chrome://myext/content/overlay.xul
locale  myext   en-US   locale/en-US/
skin    myext   classic/1.0 skin/
style       chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myext/skin/overlay.css
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://myext/skin/overlay.css
```

Any ideas why this happening ?

Let me know if i need to post contents of more files.

Thanks

Edit: 
overlay.xul >

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://myext/skin/overlay.css" type="text/css"?> 
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://myext/locale/overlay.dtd"> 
<overlay id="myext-overlay" 
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"> 

    <script src="loader.js"/>
    <script src='jquery.js'/>
    <script src="overlay.js"/>
    <script src="jquery.cookie.js"/>
    <script src="Jquery-ui.js"/>
    <script src="json2.js"/>
    <script src="script.js"/>


    <statusbar id="status-bar">
      <statusbarpanel role="button"
                        onmouseup="KH.bind_btn_click()"
                        tooltiptext="myext">
            <image src="chrome://myext/skin/icon.png" />
        </statusbarpanel>
    </statusbar>

</overlay>
```

Dir structure >

```
/content
    overlay.xul
    [otehr js files]
/locale
/skin
/chrome/manifest
/install.rdf
```

Comment: Show us your directory structure and the contents of overlay.xul

Comment: The relevant part of your overlay would be helpful.

Comment: updated the question with overlay.xul .

Comment: Could be a problem with jQuery. I had the problem once too. My advice is not to include jQuery (or any custom JavaScript) into global space (your add-on should only create a few global objects to not mess with the other add-ons).

Comment: @Felix any suggestion .. how can i use jquery without breaking FF ? ..

Comment: How to use jQuery in Firefox extension: http://stackoverflow.com/q/491490/340760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your javascript files are breaking Firefox.

The namespace on Firefox addons are global, meaning that if you use the name of something that already exists it will cause conflicts. Here is a blog post about [Global Namespace polution](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/16/firefox-extensions-global-namespace-pollution/).

Here you may find a simple article to [create namespaces for you addon](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts attempt to access the DOM before the load event fires then this will trigger XBL binding on the affected nodes before overlay loading has finished. In particular when toolbar XBL binds it attempts to restore the custom toolbar configuration however for this to work all the overlays need to have been loaded so that the buttons are all available in the palette. There will be a workaround in Firefox 4 in the specific case of the toolbar but in general you should still avoid accessing the DOM before the load event.