# Using jQuery in Firefox Addons

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

Does anyone know how to properly use jQuery in a **Firefox addon**? I've looked, but I can't find anyway that is relevant to the latest version of jQuery, and I know I can't just include it via script tag because of conflicts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dupe of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension

Comment: Not a duplicate, non of those answers apply - like I said, they either aren't the right way to do it, or don't work for 1.6.2.

Comment: sorry about that... thought for sure I saw greasemonkey in there O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the subscript loader to load JavaScript code (including JQuery) into an arbitrary scope. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/MozIJSSubScriptLoader.