# Do you know an open source Javascript extraction/regexp engine?

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, frameworks, browser-extension

We are in need of a DOM parser, that will be able to run a bunch of patterns and would store the results. For this we are looking for libraries that are open and we can start on,

- able to select elements by regexp (for example grab all elements that contain "price" either in class, id, other attributes like meta attributes),
- should have a lot of helpers like: remove comments, iframes, etc
- and be pretty fast.
- can be run from browser extensions.

Comment: jquery is great and does all things. it is good too, as well.

Comment: does it work in browser extensions?

Comment: I've never tried, but its just a javascript library. It should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) can parse HTML, provides a DOM with a number of utils (also supports filtering by functions) and can be run in any context (even in WebWorkers).

I [forked](https://github.com/fb55/node-htmlparser) it a while back, improved it for better speed and got some insane results (read: even faster than native libexpat bindings).

Nevertheless, I would advice you to use the original version, as it supports browsers out-of-the-box (my fork can be run in browsers using browserify, which adds some overhead).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll say it :
You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

**ups** :

- it is a very good dom parser
- it is very good at manipulating the dom (removing/adding/editing elements)
- it has a great and intuitive api
- it has a big & great community => lots of answers to any jquery related question
- it works in browser extensions (tested it myself in chrome and it apparently works in ff extensions too : [How to use jQuery in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension))
- it is lightweight (About 31KB in size - minified and gzipped)
- it is cross-browser
- it is definitely open source

**downs** :

- it doesn't rely on regex (although this is a **very** good thing - as [dda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136195/dda) already mentioned), but regex can be used to filter the elements
- dont know if it can access/manipulate comments

Here's an example of some jquery action :

```
// select all the iframe elements with the class advertisement 
// that have the word "porn" in their src attribute
$('iframe.advertisement[src*=porn]')
    // filter the ones that contains the word "poney" in their title 
    // with the help of a regex
    .filter(function(){
        return /poney/gi.test((this.title || this.document.title).test()));
    }) 
        // and remove them
        .remove()
        // return to the whole match
        .end()
    // filter them again, this time 
    // affect only the big ones
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).width() > 100 && $(this).height() > 100;
    })
        // replace them with some html markup
        .replaceWith('<img src="harmless_bunnies_and_kitties.jpg" />');
```

Comment: Does it work in browser extensions?

Comment: yes, it does work quite nicely. see update.