# add jQuery in Firefox extension

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, browser-extension

i searched this problem in stackoverflow but i didn't find a good solution,
so, my problem is that in my extension, jQuery doesn't work...

**extension.xul:**

```
<overlay xmlns='http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='chrome://extension/content/jQuery.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='chrome://extension/content/extension.js'></script>

    <toolbar id="nav-bar">
        <toolbarbutton id="ext-toolbarbutton" label="extension" tooltiptext="extension" type="menu">
            <menupopup>
                <menuitem id="ext-toolbar-state" type="checkbox" label="Activate" accesskey="A" checked="true" oncommand="ext.disabled"/>
            </menupopup>
        </toolbarbutton>
    </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

**extension.js**

```
function Ext(state){
    this.state = state;
}

Ext.prototype.enable = function(){
    $("#ext-toolbar-state").attr("oncommand", "ext.disabled");
}

Ext.prototype.disabled = function(){
    $("#ext-toolbar-state").attr("oncommand", "ext.enable");
}

var ext = new Ext("enable");
```

thanks !

Comment: What is the purpose of this extension ? I personally use "jQuerify" extension [firebug extension] to load jquery in any page ..

Comment: This extension is a userscript but I do not want to use greasemonkey and I don't know jquerify, where can I find documentation ?

Comment: [Firequery extension documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firequery/?src=search)

Comment: ok but i have to use jquery in my class without jquerify

Comment: Have you any constraints due to your class environment that would prevent you from including jquery the standard way  ? `:/`

Comment: i don't think, my extension and my userscript use jQuery thus i wanted  to include jQuery in this way... i am not sure that jquerify is the standard way, if an user use my extension, it will also have jquerify...

Comment: By saying standard way I meant by putting a reference to the script inside the content of the page loaded

Comment: you say that I hurt included jquery ?! so what the great way to include jQuery for use in my extension and my userscript ?

Comment: I don't know about extensions in Firefox, I must have misunderstood something

Comment: Using jquery in `XUL` does not work a lot of stuff, can clash with other add-on doing the same but with different jquery versions (therefore you'll need `.noConflict()` at least; your `ext` name might also clash with other add-ons using the same, obvious name) and is a waste of resources (load time, memory) anyway. What's wrong with just using the regular DOM APIs and avoid all that? `.getElementById()` `.setAttribute()`, etc will work just fine...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery in Firefox Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension)