# Tab independent jQuery on Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developping a Firefox based on jQuery as described in this [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension).

After implementing the example provided in the answer, eveything works fine, but the problem is the code between Firefox Tabs is somehow linked, and `example.doc` always refers to the last opened tab.

- Opened tab1 : the `plugin-example` has been added and to the current page.
- `this.doc` refers to tab1.
- Oepened tab2: the `plugin-example` has been added to to current page (tab2).
- `this.doc` now refers to tab2
- back to viewing tab1 : `this.doc` still refers to tab1.
- clicking on `plugin-example` on tab1 will act on the `plugin-example` in tab2 instead.

How can I make my code independent between tabs?

Here is an excrept from the code:

```
(function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $ = function(selector,context) { 
        return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context||example.doc); 
    };
    $.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;

    example = new function(){};

    example.run = function(doc,aEvent) {
        if (doc.getElementById("plugin-example")) return;
        this.doc = doc;
        this.main = main = $('<div id="plugin-example">').appendTo(doc.body).html('Example Loaded!');
        this.main.click(function() { //<--- added this function
                example.main.html(example.doc.location.href);
        });
        main.css({ 
            background:'#FFF',color:'#000',position:'absolute',top:0,left:0,padding:8
        });
    };
    // Bind Plugin
    var delay = function(aEvent) { 
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; setTimeout(function() { 
            example.run(doc,aEvent); 
        }, 1); 
     };
    var load = function() { 
        gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", delay, true); 
    };
    window.addEventListener("pageshow", load, false);

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (overlay script) will only run once per window, not once per tab. So there is only one `example` instance per window. And hence `example.doc` will be set to whatever dispatched `DOMContentLoaded` last.

Your function should properly close over the document and avoid global state.
This is who I would write it (then again, I would avoid jquery (in add-ons) like the plague...)

```
// Use strict mode in particular to avoid implicitly var declarations
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // Main runner function for each content window.
  // Similar to SDK page-mod, but without the security boundaries.
  function run(window, document) {
    // jquery setup. per https://stackoverflow.com/a/496970/484441
    $ = function(selector,context) {
      return new jq.fn.init(selector,context || document); 
    };
    $.fn = $.prototype = jq.fn;

    if (document.getElementById("my-example-addon-container"))  {
      return;
    }
    let main = $('<div id="my-example-addon-container">');
    main.appendTo(document.body).text('Example Loaded!');
    main.click(function() { //<--- added this function
      main.text(document.location.href);
    });
    main.css({
      background:'#FFF',color:'#000',position:'absolute',top:0,left:0,padding:8
    });
  };

  const log = Components.utils.reportError.bind(Components.utils);

  // Do not conflict with other add-ons using jquery.
  const jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);

  gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function load(evt) {
    try {
      // Call run with this == window ;)
      let doc = evt.target.ownerDocument || evt.target;
      if (!doc.location.href.startsWith("http")) {
        // Do not even attempt to interact with non-http(s)? sites.
        return;
      }
      run.call(doc.defaultView, doc.defaultView, doc);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      log(ex);
    }
  }, true);
})();
```

Here is [a complete add-on as a gist](https://gist.github.com/nmaier/d1a259435af47f6a159d). Just drop in a copy of jquery and it should be good to go.

PS: Reposted this at in the [jquery in extensions question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23776848/484441)

Comment: Would it be more robust to check if the target document is `instanceof HTMLDocument`? Checking just if it has been served over `http(s)` will also catch other types of documents (e.g. Image, SVG). Of course under circumstances this might desirable, but most probably not.

Comment: @paa Well, there might be also `chrome://` `HTMLDocument`s (which might be privileged), so at the very least I'd filter protocols. "Flat" images loaded in a tab also have an HTML container FWIW, and IIRC some other stuff as well... Also `DOMContentLoaded` should only fire if there is actually some kind of DOM. But ultimatively yeah, `instanceof HTMLDocument` might be a good *additional* check.